# Java execution in command line fails on JMX error

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, jmx, amazon-eks

We have applications running in EKS, which complain on "Address already in use" while attempting to connect with Jconsole. When we tried to run just `java -version` it fails on the same error. See exception below:

```
/home/app # java -version
Error: JMX connector server communication error: service:jmx:rmi://qa-my-app-av22b3dcbc-4322t:9110
sun.management.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9110; nested exception is: 
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:800)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:468)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:262)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:452)
        at java.lang.System.startSNMPAgent(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.completeInitialization(Thread.java:168)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.completeInitialization(J9VMInternals.java:74)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9110; nested exception is: 
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:346)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:254)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:237)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap$PermanentExporter.exportObject(ConnectorBootstrap.java:199)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:146)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:122)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:404)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:796)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:390)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:252)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:143)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:345)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
        ... 15 more
Exception in thread "main" java/lang/RuntimeException: sun.management.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9110; nested exception is: 
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at sun/management/Agent.error (Agent.java:526)
        at sun/management/Agent.startAgent (Agent.java:269)
        at sun/management/Agent.startAgent (Agent.java:452)
        at java/lang/System.startSNMPAgent (NativeMethod:4294967295)
        at java/lang/Thread.completeInitialization (Thread.java:168)
        at java/lang/J9VMInternals.completeInitialization (J9VMInternals.java:74)
```

JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS env variable value:

```
-Dspring.config.location=/home/app/config/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/home/app/config/logback.xml -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9110 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9110 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -javaagent:/home/app/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.config.file=/home/app/newrelic/config/newrelic.yml
```

The image entrypoint is simply
`ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/home/app/application.jar"]`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there's another process on that port. If it is not an important one, kill the process bia fuser, for example:

```
sudo fuser -k 9110/tcp
```

You could also check what's listening there before killing it:

```
lsof -i :9110
```

When the port is clean, try again. Another option is to change the rmi port number to something different than `9110`, as jmx doesn't require specific port numbers to work (*don't forget changing the port on the endpoint as well*).

Comment: Got it, the problem was that our JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable wasn't changing, so each time I was running ```java``` it was failing on attempt to grab the port which was occupied by the JVM app running in the container itself.

Comment: I think i didn't help at all, but hey, glad you fixed it mate : )